# How to implement a JSF Icefaces 4.0 custom theme?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am using JSF Icefaces 4.0 and trying to use the jQuery themeroller to create a custom theme. The steps I have followed are:

1. Create the custom theme and download
2. Rename the download folder to ace-mytheme
3. Place the folder under META-INF/resources
4. Package this into a .jar file
5. Place the .jar file into WEb-INF/lib
6. Change my `web.xml` to

`<context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.theme</param-name>
        <param-value>mytheme</param-value>
</context-param>`

These are the instructions as stated on the icefaces web page.

[Icefaces instructions](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Creating+a+Custom+ThemeRoller+Theme)

However, I'm not sure if I have followed them incorrectly or if they are themselves incorrect. When trying to launch my application, no theme is shown and the following error is shown in the browser

> Unable to find resource icefaces.ace, theme.css

The error on MyEclipse console is as follows:

> 19-Jan-2015 14:52:33 com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
>
> WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, theme.css, from library, ace-mytheme.

Any help with this will be appreciated.